# To customize the Bootstrap Typeahead query to render suggestions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using Bootstrap Typeahead to suggest values which will have values like

10 X 8# / 250 X 12,

12.5 X 12.4# / 318 X 18.5,

1 1/2X1 1/2X.123

etc....

So the requirement is that if in the input box user types 108, the first item in the above list should be suggested.
likewise if the user enters 1251 then the second item in the above list should be suggested 
and if user types 11 then the third item in the list shoud be suggested.

So basically we need to ignore all characters apart from numbers.

I went through some articles that talk about customization and most of them talk about customizing the suggested value by overriding the highlighter method.

So any idea how to go about this one ?

Comment: What will the actual data look like? Have you tried regex?

Comment: the actual data is of the form   10 X 8# / 250 X 12, 
in the input box use should be able to type 108 and see the above value suggested.
also, i haven't tried regex yet, but where shall I write my own regex, which method shall i override , if u have a sample that would help.I have seen the highlighter method and that is something that allows me to customize the suggestion itself not the query to fetch the suggestion.

Comment: Hey @whipdancer dancer , I got where to change and it worked for me , thank you so much :-)
I altered the subStringMatcher method , it was right in front of me all the time but somehow missed it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a customer match function, like this:

```
function fuzzyMatch(item) {
  var s1 = this.query.trim().replace(/\D/g,'');
  var s2 = item.trim().replace(/\D/g,'');

  return s2.indexOf(s1) !== -1;
}
```

You can watch my jsfiddle example here: https://jsfiddle.net/pensnarik/tqe49zqs/